# Conditional loading of PERL5LIB in .bash_profile

Tags: bash

I can't seem to get the following to work:

```
case "$PERL5LIB:" in
        *":/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl:/Users/me/perl/perl_lib:"*) :;;
        *) PERL5LIB="/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl:/Users/me/perl/perl_lib:$PERL5LIB";;
esac
```

I have done this with `$PATH` successfully but for whatever reason using this conditional loading method with `$PERL5LIB isn't taking. I have reloaded my bash profile.

UPDATE: OK, it is getting added to PERL5LIB, just not @INC.

Comment: What doesn't work? Does it not add the two paths when you think it should, or is it adding them even when they are already present. Having duplicate entries isn't going to have any significant impact on, well, anything. Just use `PERL5LIB="...:...:$PERL5LIB"` and be done with it.

Comment: They aren't getting added to the path. It's just annoying because it clutters up the output when the variable is inspected.

Comment: Actually, it is getting added to $PERL5LIB, but it's not getting added to @INC.

Comment: Doh! Accidentally deleted the export PERL5LIB line. Fixed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question stemmed from a dumb coding mistake.